# Do R modeling packages treat character variables the same as unordered factors?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have categorical variables that are character columns. For example, a character column whose values are all either "yes" or "no". Will R modeling packages correctly handle them as nominal categorical variables even if I leave them as character columns, or do these packages require them to be unordered factors?

Comment: @BenBolker I just found this question in the Close Votes review when in fact your comment should be the answer. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: So the question is "Do most R modeling packages automatically convert strings to categoricals, and do they do so correctly?" to which the answer is "Not if you expect 'yes','Yes','YES','Y' case to be merged or leading/trailing whitespace to be stripped". So don't rely on this, comvert strings -> categoricals yourself, and check they only have (say) two levels of cardinality, and/or that all NAs get converted properly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on @GaborGrothendieck's answer: the answer is "usually yes", because most statistical modeling packages make use of `model.matrix()` to handle various types of predictors, interactions, etc..

That said, it's probably best practice to convert to factors explicitly so that you have control/know what's going on. What's the downside? Converting to factors explicitly also allows to you to control order of levels, contrasts, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Each function is free to do what it wants but if the function uses `model.matrix` then it will treat character strings as factors.

### 2 levels

```
x2 <- c("yes", "no", "yes")
model.matrix(~ x2)
```

giving:

```
  (Intercept) xyes
1           1    1
2           1    0
3           1    1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$x
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

### 3 levels

```
x3 <- letters[1:3]
model.matrix(~ x3)
```

giving:

```
  (Intercept) xxb xxc
1           1   0   0
2           1   1   0
3           1   0   1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$xx
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Comment: Do most standard R modeling packages use `model.matrix`?

Comment: That is likely the case but you would have to review the source code to be absolutely sure.